# Why is it printing zero?

Tags: java

```
class A {

    final int finalValue;

    public A( B b ) {
        super();
        b.doSomething( this ); // this escapes!
        finalValue = 23;
    }

    int getTheValue() {
        return finalValue;
    }
}

class B {
    void doSomething( A a ) {
        System.out.println( a.getTheValue() );
    }
}
```

Why is it printing zero? Instead of 23? 
I have found this example on Wikipedia site

Update:
My question was very bad and i totally missed the point...
They say that pointer this goes out of scope and object wont be created fully
I wanted to ask if someone more experienced can explain that to me because im new in world of programing

Comment: order of code...

Comment: Why should it print `23`? you set `finalValue` to `23` only after you called `b.doSomething(this)`. You just discovered why leaking a premature object is a code smell and should be avoided whenever possible. Some people go so far to only call final methods from constructors for this reason.

Comment: Can you explain why you *expect* a different result than what you observe?  When you step through this in a debugger, which specific operation does something unexpected?  What did you expect that specific operation to do?  Why?

Comment: It's not that it goes "out of scope", it's that something else has access to the object before it's fully constructed.

Comment: @YCF_L  The constructor is being called otherwise nothing would happen at all. But the object under construction hasn't *finished* before something else accesses it.

Answer (score 1):

In your IDE set a breakpoint in the `getTheValue()` method and observe the stack at that point. You are calling `constructor->doSomething->getTheValue` before an assignment has been done. At that point it is still 0, the guarantee is that it assigned during the construction phase and not modified after, which is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this to fix the issue:

```
public A( B b ) {
    super();
    finalValue = 23;
    b.doSomething( this ); // this escapes!
}
```

Comment: Despite the fact that OP asked why it prints `23` (not how to fix it), this is equally bad since it still leaks a premature object.

Comment: @Turing85: I agree on your comment.

Comment: @Milan Srdić: Would you please upvote this answer? I just upvoted your question.